# "Updates not installed" after updating all applications in app store

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, mac-appstore, software-update

after 4 months I turned on my **MacBook Air [2015]** and first off all I tried install *JDK 8* and *Eclipse* for developing python.  after all things done, I notified by app store update notification so I clicked to update all of applications. but this things happened.

1. after downloading all files, iTunes 12.8.2, Safari 12.0.3 and Security Update 2019-001 10.12.6 it shows this message:
   [image: so I clicked on download & restart]
2. ok, now everything is good and waiting for progress bar to complete:
   [image: anytime I tried after failure restart, it started at 1.12 Gb!]
3. and after downloading things wait for restart:
   [image: ...]
4. it shows OS update progress:
   [image: but wait, it's good just for 5 secondes]
5. and error happened :
   [image: and I clicked restart]
6. MacBook restarted and go to MacOS again
7. and now this message showing up:
   [image: ...]
8. and now if i click on install, it goes to step one again. and everything repeated as I said in this list.

Machine Specs:

- MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
- MacBook Air (13 inch - early 2015)
- 8Gb DDR3
- and about 20Gb free space

Comment: Did you successfully install JDK8 and Eclipse ? Do you think those have anything to do with Safari ? Was the Safari running at the time ?

Comment: @Ruskes yes I installed it and now everything is good. I don't think any relation between this problem and jdk, because i uninstalled those two apps and everything is like past. nothing chaned

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your installed copy of Safari became corrupted.

Delete Safari, then reinstall your current version of macOS.  That will reinstall a good copy of Safari, and then you should be able to install any updates.

Comment: I'll try. but how can I do that. I searched for safari uninstallation but I found some third party apps. I don't want to use that apps. why there is no built-in tool for MacOS apps removal

Comment: There is no built-in tool for macOS app removal because none is needed.

To delete an app, just drag it to the Trash icon on your Dock.